# How to get the API name of the fields used as a filter within a report?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, fields, reports-api

I'm trying to get the fields used within a report.
By using Reports.ReportManager.describeReport I'm able to get a lot of information about the report. Unfortunatly I'm not getting the API name of the fields which were used as filters.

How can I get this?

Thanks,
Ts

Answer (score 1):

If you go into your report you can find the field names by right clicking and inspecting element: [image]

Note that in mine, the value for the account ID is FK_ACC_ID, so they might not look exactly like the image above.

Credit to [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtuZAAQ/)